# What is this electrical symbol?

Tags: identification, symbol, diagram

I'm trying to identify this symbol coming from a 1985 electrical single line diagram (from a marine engineering project).

It looks like a closed disconnector switch or a styled fuse maybe?

[image]

Here is some context around the symbol:

[image]

Comment: It is a  Дюкер !

Comment: What would it be in english? Gas pipe?

Comment: who knows "Syphon"  anti-galvanic connection to prevent corrosion on pipe line  to siphon electron collision to earth rather than corrode pipe. " cathodic protection type "

Comment: It looks like a sliding earth-link to me. I can't find a reference.

Comment: Looks like a fusible link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a cartridge circuit breaker as per [this website](https://www.electrical-symbols.com/electric-electronic-symbols/fuse-protection-symbols.htm) entitled Electrical and Electronic symbols: -

[image]

The bigger question will inevitably be - did the person making the diagram back in 1985 adhere to the standards or, were the standards of today the same as they were in 1985.